# Tracking untagged adwords visits in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-ads

In the event an AdWords campaign doesn't tag its ads, is there any way to identify the traffic (I know I won't get the low-level type of reporting available through properly tagged campaigns, I just want to get a general idea).

For instance, is there any way to narrow it down by Source / Medium (would it appear as Google / Organic, Google / Referral, or Direct / None)?

Comment: Why not use the adwords desktop program to tag all your URL's in a csv file then import them to your campaigns?

Comment: @Anagio because that doesn't solve my problems or address my question. If you go through a campaign and at the end realize that the URLs weren't tagged, how do you go back in Analytics to identify those clicks that weren't tagged?

Comment: Do these two areas in Analytics not provide details on your visitors who came through a campaign

Trafic Source -> Sources -> Campaigns
and
Advertising -> Campaigns

Comment: @Anagio No, they do not. Because they are untagged, Google Analytics doesn't recognize it as a valid campaign. My hope is that there's still some sort of "fingerprint" or clue in the recorded data which would help me identity them (i.e. if they were recorded as referral through Google's CDN, but that hasn't been the case for a great many years).

Comment: Well you can test it by having a friend click on an ad while you watch your live stream of visitors and see if it shows up as Google Organic or Google Referral traffic. I thought you had auto tagging setup if you didn't tag your URL's manually. In traffic sources - sources - referral you may be able to drill down if that's where they're appearing. Though this traffic accounts for all other Google services such as image search etc but again you can drill that down.